# Ускороить сотрировку таблицы

Tags: javascript, html

Есть функция сотрировки, и так как записай более 500 она работает очень медленно. Как можно ускорить этот процесс или что я делаю не так?

```
function sortTable(n) {
  var table, rows, switching, shouldSwitch, direction;
  var switchCount = 0;
  switching = true;
  direction = "asc";

  var headers = document.getElementsByTagName('th');
  for (var i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
    headers[i].classList.remove('contacts__table-sortable_asc', 'contacts__table-sortable_desc');
  }
  while (switching) {
    headers[n].classList.add('contacts__table-sortable_' + direction);
    switching = false;
    rows = $('.contacts__table-row');
    for (var i = isEditing ? 1 : 0; i < (rows.length - 1); i++) {
      shouldSwitch = false;
      var x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
      var y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
      if (direction === "asc") {
        if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() > y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
          shouldSwitch = true;
          break;
        }
      } else if (direction === "desc") {
        if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() < y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
          shouldSwitch = true;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    if (shouldSwitch) {
      rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
      switching = true;
      switchCount++;
    } else {
      if (switchCount === 0 && direction === "asc") {
        direction = "desc";
        switching = true;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Сама таблица

```
<table id="table" class="contacts__table" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th><input onchange="selectAllRows(this)" class="contacts__table-checkbox" type="checkbox"></th>
      <th class="contacts__table-sortable contacts__table-sortable_narrow" onclick="sortTable(1)">Title</th>
      <th class="contacts__table-sortable contacts__table-sortable_narrow" onclick="sortTable(2)">Name</th>
      <th class="contacts__table-sortable contacts__table-sortable_narrow" onclick="sortTable(3)">Surname</th>
      <th class="contacts__table-sortable" onclick="sortTable(4)">Email</th>
      <th>Note</th>
      <th class="contacts__table-sortable" onclick="sortTable(6)">Tags</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php foreach ($contacts as $contact) { ?>
    <tr id="tr<?php echo $contact->id ?>" onclick="toggleRowSelected(this)" class="contacts__table-row">
      <td><input class="contacts__table-checkbox" type="checkbox"></td>
      <td>
        <?php echo $contact->title ?>
      </td>
      <td>
        <?php echo $contact->name ?>
      </td>
      <td>
        <?php echo $contact->surname ?>
      </td>
      <td class="contacts__table-email"><span class="table-overflow"><?php echo $contact->email ?></span></td>
      <td><span class="table-overflow"><?php echo $contact->note ?></span></td>
      <td><span class="table-overflow"><?php echo $contact->tags ?></span></td>
      <td><label onclick="editContact('tr<?php echo $contact->id ?>')" class="contacts__table-btn contacts__table-btn_edit"></label></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Может использовать готовые решения типа https://datatables.net/ ? Ну а если самому "делать велосипед" я бы подгружал таблицу в json формате и производил бы операции с ним и "перерисовывал" таблицу. А так тебе помимо прочего каждый раз приходится насиловать DOM.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема не в сортировке, а в отрисовке. 500 строк в таблице рендерится медленно. Нужно воспользоваться библиотеками типа window-rendering, т.е. рендерить только то, что влезает в экран просмотра. И вообще сортировать нужно данные, а не узлы таблицы и потом стирать и заново отрисовывать таблицу уже по отсортированных данных